# Find a solution of $u_{xx}+u_{yy} = Ax+By+C$ for given real constants $A,B$ and $C$. How many more solutions can be produced?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, proof-verification, proof-writing

1. Observe that $u_1(x,y)=x^2$ solves $u_{xx}+u{yy} =2$ and $u_2(x,y) =cx^3+dy^3$ solves $u_{xx}+u_{yy} =6cx+6dy$ for real constants $c$ and $d$.

Question: a. Find a solution of $u_{xx}+u_{yy} = Ax+By+C$ for given real constants $A,B$ and $C$.

My attempt:

We need to find a solution that satisfies $u_{xx}+u_{yy} = Ax+By+C$.

First, we notice that we are working with two variables: x and y. Since x only appears next to A, we assume that the y variable must be next to B and C.

Suppose we have the following equation: $\frac{1}{6}Ax^3+\frac{1}{6}By^3+\frac{1}{2}Cy^2$

Taking the first partial derivatives in terms of x and y, we have,

$u_x = \frac{1}{2}Ax^2$ and $u_y = \frac{1}{2}By^2+Cy$

Adding $u_x$ and $u_y$ produces the following result:

$u_x+u_y=\frac{1}{2}Ax^2+\frac{1}{2}By^2+Cy$

Taking the derivatives of $u_x$ and $u_y$, we have

$u_{xx} =Ax$ and $u_{yy} = By+C$

Adding $u_{xx}$ and $u_{yy}$ gives us $Ax+By+C$, so we have proven that $\frac{1}{6}Ax^3+\frac{1}{6}By^3+\frac{1}{2}Cy^2$ satisfies $u_{xx}+u_{yy} = Ax+By+C$.

---

Question: b. How many more solutions of the problem in $(a)$ be produced?

Ok. This is where I get stuck... well not exactly stuck more like unsure. This is what I think. Suppose we have fractions with bigger denominators, then it would be impossible to achieve $Ax+By+C$.

For example, suppose we have an equation $\frac{1}{12}Ax^3+\frac{1}{12}By^3+\frac{1}{6}y^2C$

Taking the $u_x$ and $u_y$ we have

$\frac{1}{4}Ax^2+\frac{1}{4}By^2+\frac{1}{3}yC$

and the $u_{xx}$ and $u_{yy}$

would be $\frac{1}{2}Ax+\frac{1}{2}By+\frac{1}{3}C$ Unless I am able to multiply by 2 and manipulate the C part, then the equation won't match.

Also, the question did say whether or not we are able to generate more solutions that will satisfy $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=Ax+By+C$ which is a very strict condition. It doesn't say that we can have an integer that would allow us to multiply through the left side to equal the right side.

If we have fractional exponents then we have to consider that the exponent will change when we take the derivative and if we have a $e^x$ then taking the derivative will keep the $e^x$ and that doesn't satisfy the equation either. Therefore, no additional solutions can be produced.

Comment: Suppose $v$ is a different solution, and $u$ is the solution you found. Then what equation does $u-v$ satisfy?

Comment: So I have to subtract v which would be a different solution and u which is $\frac{1}{6}Ax^3+\frac{1}{6}By^3+\frac{1}{2}Cy^2$?

Comment: If you have $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=Ax+By+C$ and $v_{xx}+v_{yy}=Ax+By+C$ and you put $w=u-v$, then what is $w_{xx}+w_{yy}$?

Comment: that is the same equation twice! The second part of the problem asks are there any more solutions that will satisfy whatever I wrote down.  Anyway,this is strange. so you want 
$u_{xx}+v_{xx}+u_{yy}+v_{yy}$ and then since $ w =u-v$ so that's now $ w_{xx}+w_{yy}$.... if I take $w_u$ that's 1 and $w_v $ is -1...argh,,, confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Laplace-operator $\Delta=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}$, your equation writes
$$
\Delta u = Ax + By + C.
$$
Now, if both $u$ and $v$ are solutions of this equation, we obtain by considering the difference $\Delta(u-v)=0$. Functions $h\in C^2$ with $\Delta h=0$ are called harmonic. Conversely, if $u$ is a solution and $h$ is harmonic, then $u+h$ is again a solution. This shows the following: Whenever you have found one solution, then every other solution can be generated by adding a harmonic function!

Comment: So what I need to find is another 2 variable harmonic function, and then take the difference of that function with the solution that I already found. let's see $x^2+y^2+z^2$ is a three variable . .. so what about... wait I already found $Dx+Ey$ ... hmm. I know that when h is in $C^2$ that would mean that there is a second order derivative that's continuous. I think that applies to partial derivatives as well.

Comment: oh wait I need a $u_{xx}+u_{yy}$ and $v_{xx}+v_{yy}$ that would equal to $Ax+Bx+C$

Comment: Your question was: How many other solutions has your equation? And you cannot give all solutions explicitly, but the set of all solutions if given by $\{u+h\ |\ h\ $harmonic$\}$. So this is how I would answer the question.

Comment: Now it looks like $u+h$ divides h harmonic . What does that mean? I know that if there are two additional constants with single variables x and y, that's one. Someone mentioned adding sinhxsiny to my equation, so I tried to take the partial derivatives and for $u_x$ I have $coshx$ and for $u_y$ is $cosy$. I kind of forgot if I should include the $siny$ when taking the partial derivative of $u_x$ so it would be like $coshxsiny$, but I think it's ... hmmm I think the part that only matters is the x, not y.

Comment: As I said, you cannot give all solutions explicitly. But each solution has the form $u+h$, where $u$ is your solution constructed above, and $h$ is an arbitrary harmonic function. So the SET of all solutions is given by $\{u+h\ :\ h\ $harmonic$\}$. (I replaced the $|$ by $:$, if you are more familiar with this notation).

Comment: Which means that it would be impossible to find all the solutions out there, but the solution has the form of $u-v$ and $u+h$ if the there are harmonic equations and u is a solution. Don't I have to give some examples or something like that? Besides the equation I have found + Dx+Ey

Comment: You cannot write down each solution, because there are infinitly many (because there are infinitly many harmonic functions which can be added to $u$). The function $h(x,y):=Dx + Ey$ is one example of a harmonic function. But there are many more. The function $h(x,y):=e^x\sin(y)$ is another example.

Comment: ok I'm trying to take the partial derivative $u_x$ of $e^xsiny$ and that's just $e^x$ and $u_xx = e^x$. $u_y = cosy$ and $u_yy=-siny$. How do those terms disappear. Unless I include the y and x

$u_x = (siny)e^x$ and $u_xx = (siny)e^x$
$u_y=e^x(cosy)$ and $u_yy = -e^xsiny$
$u_xx+u_yy = (siny)e^x-e^xsiny$ and that's 0

Comment: No. If $h=e^x\sin(y)$, then $h_{xx}=e^x\sin(y)$ and $h_{yy}=-e^x\sin(y)$, so $h_{xx}+h_{yy}=0$. That is, $h$ is harmonic.

Comment: Oh! I must've used the wrong letters, but I do have the $xx$ as $sinye^x$ and $yy$ as $-e^xsiny$... so if I add those $xx$ and $yy$ I have 0... the comments section is super messy when it comes to latex.

Comment: So, are we agreed? :)

Comment: yeah, but I am still a bit confused... so there are a lot of harmonic equations that would satisfy $u_xx+u_yy = 0$ . We can't list them all, but we know that if u is a solution and h is a harmonic function then we have u+h = 0 ?

Comment: There are a lot of harmonic functions $h$ (which means they satisfy $h_{xx}+h_{yy}=0$). If $u$ is a solution of your problem, then so is $u+h$. But I have written this three times now...

Answer (score 0):

You have found one solution to the equation. Now you want to find other solutions. Suppose you add $Dx$ to your solution. What happens. Well, if you differentiate $Dx$ (where $D$ is just a constant) twice wrt $x$ or twice wrt $y$ you get nil. So your solution $+Dx$ is also a solution. Similarly you can add $Ey$ and still have a solution.

The usual way of approaching this to say that if $u=f(x,y)$ is another solution, then we can put $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{6}Ax^3+\frac{1}{6}By^3+\frac{1}{2}Cy^2+g(x,y)$. Then $g$ must satisfy the equation $g_{xx}+g_{yy}=0$, so we just have to solve that equation.

Comment: oh now I'm starting to get it.. so I have to add more variables like Dx+Ey and then proceed as normal since taking the $u_{xx}$ and $u_{yy}$ makes the Dx and Ey disappear but I will still have the A B and C satisfying the condition  .  Could that also work if I add .... Dx+Ex+Fy+Gy and then by taking the second partial derivatives then those letters would be gone too?

Comment: so basically it's not about manipulating the original equation like finding more combinations of numbers so it satisfies the equation and requirements . It's about the variables!

Comment: Well yes and no. $Dx+Ex$ is no more general than $Dx$. Any value you can get with $D+E$ you can also get with just $D$.

Comment: So the answer to the second part is yes if we add another constant D with the variable x and the constant E with the variable y. Taking the second partial derivatives with respect to x and y we eliminate the D and E, but still retain the original equation of Ax+By+C

Comment: That is the idea. The question now is how to be sure you have got them all (if you have).

Comment: got them all? What do you mean? I think that as long as we have just a single variable x and y, it would be easy to produce another equation that would satisfy the requirement. If we have a $Dx^2$ then we could use a fraction but the D would be floating around and we don't want that.

Comment: Well unfortunately there are more. Try for example $\sinh x\sin y$ (plus your original solution, of course).

Comment: well suppose we do have $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{6}Ax^3+\frac{1}{6}By^3+\frac{1}{2}Cy^2+sinh x siny $ . Then taking the first partial derivative of $u_x$ and $u_y$  I get $u_x + u_y = \frac{1}{4}Ax^2+\frac{1}{4}By^2+\frac{1}{3}yC + sin y cosh x + sinh x cos y$ and

Comment: oh I forgot to finish this and the $u_x+u_y$ that I wrote is all wrong. It's $\frac{1}{2}Ax^2+\frac{1}{2}y^2B+Cy +sinycoshx+sinhxcosy$ and the $u_{xx}+u_{yy} = Ax^2+By+C +sinysinhx-sinhxsiny$ and those $sinysinhx-sinhxsiny$ cancel out. Wow I must have been doing this in my sleep :/